# Nuxt 3/Docker/Kubernetes Environment Variables

Tags: docker, kubernetes, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I have a new Nuxt 3 application. In my config.ts, I have the following variables defined:

```js
    runtimeConfig: {
        // Private keys are only available on the server
        // Public keys that are exposed to the client
        public: {
            baseUrl: process.env.NUXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL || '<url>',
            communityId: process.env.NUXT_ENV_COMMUNITY_ID || <id>,
        }
    },
```

I have this application built to a docker image, then deployed to Kubernetes as a pod/deployment, alongside a configmap which holds the 2 variables I defined earlier.

When I SSH into the pod, and run `echo $NUXT_ENV_COMMUNITY_ID`, I can see the ID I set in the configmap, and same story with the base url, however when I try to access the variables in Nuxt, they default to their default options. If I remove the defaults, the app crashes/returns a 500 error since they are not defined.

Any suggestions?

--EDIT YAML--

Deployment

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: <app name>-deployment
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: <app name>
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: <app name>
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: <app name>
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: regcred
      containers:
        - name: <container name>
          image: <my-image>
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000
          envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: <app name>-config
```

Configmap

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: <app name>-config
  namespace: default
data:
  NUXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL: "<url>"
  NUXT_ENV_COMMUNITY_ID: "2"
```

Comment: Do you in fact set the environment variables from the ConfigMap; what is in your Deployment YAML file?

Comment: I'll update the post now @DavidMaze

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/going-further/runtime-config#environment-variables.

You can set your variables as empty strings in `runtimeConfig.public`.
I also notice there's no `_PUBLIC_` on the second one, might be the issue.

Comment: Changing it to '' instead of the env variable worked, thanks